# Get all certificates installed on Local machine

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have the following code to get the certificates:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("??","??");
            List<X509Certificate2> lst = new List<X509Certificate2>();
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
            {

                lst.Add(mCert);
                //TODO's
            }
```

> Now I want to get all the certificates installed on *Local Machine* in
>   a list<> with Certificate Name, Their location, Issued with Public key
>   Or Private Key(in Yes or No only) and the name of folder which
>   contains those certs(please refer below snapshot):

[image]

After populating List<> with Certs details I want to display those data in a grid format. How to modify this code to get above details?

Comment: Getting such a list in PowerShell is a matter of recursively enumerating the `Cert:` "drive". So it is possible.

Comment: @Richard can you please show me how to achieve this through powershell?

Comment: `get-childitem cert: -recurse` is a start,

Comment: @Richard, it is throwing exception at UserDS storeName after traversing TrustedPublisher, MCafee Trust and Root storeNames. could you please provide complete working powershell script. thanks

Comment: You'll need to say what exception (it worked on my machine...)

Comment: exception -
Get-ChildItem : The specified network resource or device is no longer availableAt line:1 char:1
+ get-childitem cert: -recurse
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certificates on your machine stored in a different stores, so you need open all of them. Please see that [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename(v=vs.110).aspx)
 article.

Code example:

```
public class CertDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HasPrivateKey { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
}

// stores and they friendly names
var stores = new Dictionary<StoreName, string>()
{
    {StoreName.My, "Personal"},
    {StoreName.Root, "Trusted roots"},
    {StoreName.TrustedPublisher, "Trusted publishers"}
    // and so on
    }.Select(s => new {store = new X509Store(s.Key, StoreLocation.LocalMachine), location = s.Value}).ToArray();

foreach (var store in stores)
    store.store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly); // open each store

var list = stores.SelectMany(s => s.store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>()
    .Select(mCert => new CertDetails
    {
        HasPrivateKey = mCert.HasPrivateKey ? "Yes" : "No",
        Name = mCert.FriendlyName,
        Location = s.location,
        Issuer = mCert.Issuer
    })).ToList();
```

Comment: it is working fine but I want Local machine certs also but seems like it is giving only Current user certs, could you please modify the code to solve my issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

A short example for your inspiration, maybe it helps a bit:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
X509Store store = null;
store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
...

//RSA CryptoServiceProvider
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = null;

string keyPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\";

string friendlyName = "";

foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates) {

  rsaCSP = mCert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

  if (rsaCSP != null) {
    friendlyName = mCert.FriendlyName;                    
    keyPath += rsaCSP.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName;
  }                        
}
```

Comment: It returns nothing when I create the object using- 
X509Store store = new X509Store();

Comment: It is fetching only 2 certificates while there are so many certificates installed on my local machine.

Comment: But it does it. I think you have to change the store (look for StoreName.My to other value) or the certificate type.